# .htaccess - When there is no requested URI

Tags: .htaccess

I'm looking to do a `.htaccess` file that let any requests pass to its original destination but redirects to a specific folder (a splash screen in this case) is no destination is specified. I'm not very well-versed with `.htaccess` and would appreciate some help.

Example: I'm requesting http://www.domain.com/folder/file.php, it should go through. But if I'm requesting http://www.domain.com/, it should redirect to http://www.domain.com/splash/.

What I have so far redirects correctly to `/splash/`, but redirects ***everything*** to `/splash/`.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # If the requested URI is empty...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^$

    # ...then redirect to the "splash" folder
    RewriteRule .* splash [L]

    # Otherwise rewrite the base
    RewriteBase /

    # If the request is not a folder or a file, redirects to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks!

EDIT: One important point would be to redirect http://www.domain.com/ to http://www.domain.com/splash/, but allow direct access to http://www.domain.com/index.php.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `%{REQUEST_URI}` variable includes a leading slash, so it will NEVER be blank. You can get rid of that and just use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ /splash/ [L,R]
```

If you want the URL that appears in the browser's address bar to stay `http://www.domain.com/`, then remove the `,R` from the square brackets: `[L]`.

Comment: It works partially. I'm now able to access http://domain.com/folder/, but http://domain.com/index.php is still redirecting to http://domain.com/splash/.

Comment: @RémiBreton `index.php` shouldn't match `^/?$`, are you sure this isn't a browser caching issue?

Comment: Positive. Cleared cache, multiple browsers, multiple machines, all the same result: goes straight to `/splash/`. Appreciating the help!

Comment: @RémiBreton Does the  `/splash/` folder actually exist? Or does it get routed through index.php?

Comment: @RémiBreton No idea then, I have the rule above (without the `R`), then everything in your htaccess file after `# Otherwise rewrite the base` right after it, in a blank htaccess file on a newly installed apache 2.2, created a "splash" directory and I get shown the contents of "splash" when I request `/`, and get the index.php file when I request `/index.php`, or anything else, like `/asdashfakfh`. So it works for me.

Comment: Maybe it's something in my apache installation. Your solution still does what I needed so I'm marking it as accepted. Thanks so much for the effort!