# .htaccess, redirect to subfolder when no url segment

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect, routes

I've developed a CI website, and hosted on server root directory, I also created some static html page and put them in `website` directory. (See below)

```
public_html
     /application
     /other ci folder
     /index.php
     /.htaccess
     /website // in this directory i have my static html website
```

So when i enter `www.myweb.com` i can access my CI application,
CI application have 2 main routes.

```
www.myweb.com for front end
www.myweb.com/admin backend
```

and right now I'm able to access static html site using 
`www.myweb.com/website`

**what i want is:**

When i enter

`www.myweb.com` it should show static html website

`www.myweb.com/app` it should show front end of ci website

`www.myweb.com/admin` it should work as it is working now

**what i've tried is:**

I searched on google/stack overflow and found some **.htaccess** solutions,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine On

     RewriteBase /
     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?myweb\.com$ [NC]
     RewriteRule !^website/ /website%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
     #above line works good and show website from website folder

     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?myweb\.com$ [NC]
     RewriteRule (.*)/ %{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
     #when i add these two line website shows 500 internal server error

     #Other CI htaccess code to remove index.php
</IfModule>
```

Can you suggest me solutions. thanks

Comment: You have it all backwards. That's not something you should fix with rewrites. Create your web structure correctly the first time. If you want CI in `/app`, then create a folder `/app` and put it there. The move `/website` files to main document root. That's what I would do instead of unnecessary rewrites.

Comment: @PanamaJack: If i will move my application inside /app, it will also change my admin url(`www.myweb.com/admin` to `www.myweb.com/app/admin`), I don't want that.

Comment: Then use an alias to map admin to /app/admin. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias BTW for security purposes, I never want my admin directory easily accessible to the public. `/admin` is an easy target. That makes it easier to get attacked or brute force your admin page. You should think more about security rather than convenience.

Comment: @PanamaJack: Thank you for security suggestion, I always take care of it, In this webapp I do not have admins as super users, they are just registered users. who can add comments in app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my question, I want to share it will all

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # If the requested URI is empty...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^$

    # ...then redirect to the "website" folder
    ^/?$ /website/ [L] //or[L,R] if you want to redirect

    # Otherwise rewrite the base
    RewriteBase /

    # If the request is not a folder or a file, redirects to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I merged my assets with codeigniter assets (Corrected few paths of css and js) so it worked for me.

Hope it will work for someone.

Took help from this post: [.htaccess - When there is no requested URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13882565/htaccess-when-there-is-no-requested-uri)